# As QA tester, when do we need to do exploratory testing in Scrum?

Tags: scrum, exploratory

As QA tester, when do we need to do exploratory testing in Scrum?

Comment: Note the tag wiki: [tag:scrum].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scrum does not have a recomandation for the timing of doing the exploratory testing.Scrum consider that testing, as any other activities like design..., is a part of the development effort needed to consider that the item/US is done. So exploratory tests should be done during all the development process of the US and they have specially more sense after passing all the planned tests with success, but they should be done certainly before considering the item DONE .

Answer (score 0):

It is never too late to find a bug. But it is better earlier than later.

So ultimately you should decide with your team when you can set aside some time for that. Maybe you can prioritize which type of testing is the most important to your team, which the second important etc.
For example acceptance testing first, then exploratory testing.
If you don't have time to do both before devclose, maybe you can do the exploratory testing at the beginning of the next sprint, when no UAT have to be done, yet.